# String index out of range: 0 Error For using RedirectAttributes in Spring Boot

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, exception

```
@PostMapping("reduce_stock")
public String reduceStockPost(@RequestParam("product_id") String productId,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    String message = productManagementService.reduceStockToProduct(Long.parseLong(productId));
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",message);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass","danger");
    return "redirect:";
}
```

I got **String index out of range** error while using the **RedirectAttributes**. 
The code works properly when the RedirectAttributes is removed.

Why it gives **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** while using RedirectAttributes?

Any suggestion to improve this code snippet is a helping hand because am a newbie to java.

Comment: put you exception message please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is because you haven't pass any view name to redirect. Something like below:

```
return "redirect:/showData";
```

Comment: It works.. but how could I redirect to the same page? Is there anyway?

Comment: create another @GETMAPPING with the same url pattern and return the view name from there... and from the post mapping return like  "redirect:/reduce_stock"...